# Convert grease pencil strokes to an extruded mesh preserving stroke thickness

Tags: grease-pencil

I've googled different ways to convert the grease pencil stroke to the mesh. Unfortunately, they all do not respect the stroke thickness, because all the ways that I found use direct conversion to lines/bezier curves/polygon curves. That makes lines have even thickness instead of the thickness of a stroke:
[image: converted to polycurve]

So I have found a workaround: I apply the "Outline" modifier to the stroke first, then I convert the stroke to the polyline, then to mesh, then select all the edges and extrude them, so I have an outline as an extruded mesh:

[image: extruded mesh without caps]

But this isn't a solution because the extruded mesh does not have caps, having a hole instead. I've tried to fill it using Alt+F, but it fails to fill holes on the complex shapes, especially when line intersects itself. I've tried to autosplit intersecting edges and then Alt+F it again, but it fails to fill the holes correctly because the line is concave:
[image: concave fill failure]

Answer (score 2):

Since Blender 3.4.1, in Draw Mode of a GP Stroke, there's a checkbox **Outline** in the top menu bar under *Stroke*.

[image]

This amazing new feature creates not the center line of the Stroke, but instead creates the perimeter Line (inluding varying thickness from pen tablet):

[image]

So, this might be a good start. Depending on your Stroke geometry, you might want to use a Simplify Modifier on it. If you have overlapping strokes, try the **Cutter** in Draw Mode. For cleanup, convert Stroke to Polyline, convert again to Mesh and **Merge at Center** in Edit Mode:
[image]
[image]

After cleanup, select all and hit **Alt+F** to fill.
[image]

This can fail at the caps of the stroke, depending on geometry. Just fill the failed areas with Ngons (select that area's border, then just hit **F**).

Finally, add a **Solidify** Modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the outline stroke mode is an amazing feature.  But still, If I need to manually cut and fill the intersections this ain't gonna work while making a solid from a big illustration with lots of strokes. Anyway, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The one working workaround I have finally found:

- Turn on the Freestyle SVG Import/Export plugin
- Export Grease Pencil strokes as an SVG
- Convert exported SVG with strokes to an SVG with pathes (I googled "svg convert stroke to path online" and clicked the first link)
- Import the converted file back to blender, but not as Grease Pencil, but just as a curves collection. These curves are closed polygons of the strokes preserving their thickness, so they could be easily joined with `Ctrl+J`, then `Tab` to edit mode, `a` to select them all, `e` to extrude them.

But still this looks ad-hoc and need additional external tools to be used, so I'm still seeking for a clean solution just inside Blender.